# Duplex callback is always anonymous

Tags: c#, wcf, duplex, servicehost, wcf-callbacks

I've written a WCF duplex service and client.  Everything works well until I try to call .Demand() in the client implementation.  It appears that the the service invokes the callback method Anonymously.  I think I am missing how to correctly configure the service.

Code used to create ServiceHost;

```
ServiceHost duplex = new ServiceHost(new ServerWCallbackImpl());           
NetTcpBinding secureBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
secureBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
duplex.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IServerWithCallback),
    secureBinding,
    "net.tcp://localhost:9080/DataService");
Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name); //<-- this correctly shows the current principal
duplex.Open();
if (duplex.State == CommunicationState.Opened) 
    ((ServerWCallbackImpl)duplex.SingletonInstance).Send("Hello World!");
```

Code used to create client;

```
CallbackImpl callbackInstance = new CallbackImpl();
NetTcpBinding secureBinding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
secureBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
DuplexChannelFactory<IServerWithCallback> cf = new DuplexChannelFactory<IServerWithCallback>(
    callbackInstance,
    secureBinding,
    new EndpointAddress(requestingEndpointAddress));           
cf.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
cf.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = (NetworkCredential)CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
IServerWithCallback srv = cf.CreateChannel(new InstanceContext(callbackInstance));
srv.InitiateConversation();
```

Client implementation:

```
public void MethodOnClient(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);  // <-- anonymous
    PrincipalPermission p = new PrincipalPermission(@"DOMAIN\User", null);
    p.Demand();  // <-- fails
}
```

How can I configure so that the ServiceHost correctly invokes the Callback with Windows credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Does setting TokenImpersonationLevel to Delegation instead of Impersonation? Like this:

```
cf.Credentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088.aspx).

Comment: Grave digger? :) Question was asked Feb 18 '09 and asking user was deleted for inactivity, I guess long time ago.